# Details on soft decision trees

Tags: neural-network, decision-trees

In [*Distilling a Neural Network Into a Soft Decision Tree*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09784) the authors mention

> exponentially decaying running average of the actual probabilities with a time window

but provide no formula for it.

What does it mean speaking formal?

Comment: Interesting paper. Note that in this question you are referring to how the tree is built in order to help distile the knowledge in a NN

Answer (score 1):

This is likely the [Exponential Moving Average function.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average)
In simplest form it is

```
ma_new = alpha * new_sample + (1-alpha) * ma_old
```

Where `alpha` is the parameter that controls rate of decay, between 0.0-1.0.